# Guzzle get value from property with dash symbol?

Tags: php, guzzle

when I make a request with Guzzle:

```
$response = json_decode($client->get($uri)->getBody()->getContents());

var_dump($response); die;
```

I get this in var_dump:

```
stdClass (object) [Object ID #2395][3 properties]
contacts: 
(array) [250 elements]
has-more: (boolean) true 
vid-offset: (integer) 111259
```

When I make `$response->contacts` I get all contacts, no problem there but this `vid-offset` has a `-` in it's name so this doesn't work:

```
$response->vid-offset
```

and I tried this also:

```
$response['vid-offset'];
```

And I get this error: `Cannot use object of type stdClass as array`

I've also tried doing :

```
$response->getAttribute('vid-offset')
```

But it still didn't work.

How to get the value of `vid-offset` property?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get it this way :

```
$response->{'vid-offset'};
```